# How to load multiple file images as data url and change them individually afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

On an HTML page, there are two images set using img element. I want to change each of the image by browsing the pc directory. There is no database. After an image is changed, if the page reloads, the old image will be shown.
i.e. there are input options under each image. If I want to change 2nd image, then I will click 'choose file' option under that 2nd image which will open the window for selecting a single image.

I got a piece of code.

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>
 <img id='output' width=20>

<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>
 <img id='output' width=20>

<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>
 <img id='output' width=20>

<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
  var dataURL = reader.result;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.src = dataURL;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
</script>
```

Using this code, I could upload image for only one img element. But if I want to use it for two img elements, it doesn't work if I change id 'output' to class 'output'. I need to uderstand the reason of it and possible solutions for multiple number of images.

https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader

Comment: How are you selecting the image to change? I mean selecting from the "two images set".

Comment: You need to change "getElementById" to "getElementsByClassName" if you want to use a class instead of a id attribute

Comment: While attempting, I changed to 'getElementByClassName'. is it 'getElementsByClassName' ? AFTER EDIT -  It doesn't work.

Comment: Switching to classes helps only, if you're selecting more than one image file from the Open file window. If you want to change the images one by one, you need to somehow select the image to change.

Comment: @Nickname it should be getElementsByClassName[0] or getElementsByClassName[1] because it send an array in responce

Comment: for changing each image, I will select only one image from the open file window. There is 'choose file' option for changing each image.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan, if there are 20 img element, do I need to write same code of function for 20 times from getElementsByClassName[0] to getElementsByClassName[19] ?

Comment: No just pass a variable into the function I and use it like getElementsByClassName[i] and add the function in the loop

Comment: Can you show the "choose file option", that's a very important part of the solution.

Comment: @Teemu ... here is a link of demo - http://jsfiddle.net/8b93u7tp/

Comment: But there's only a single image in the demo. The question is, how do you select the image element of which source you want to change, if there's more than one image element, and you don't want to select multiple sources at once. Would you cllick the target image first? Would you add a checkbox next to the target image? Or perhaps an own "Change source" button for every image element?

Comment: Multiple file upload on a time u asking for ?

Comment: There will be an input option under each image like the demo link. Say, if I want to change the second image, I will click on 'choose file' option under that second image which will open window for selecting pictures from computer directory.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's what we wanted to know. Please add that to the question too. In that case you can simply set `output = input.previousElementSibling;`, or if the input element is before the image element `output = input.nextElementSibling;`.

Comment: Then update the question with recent Dom

Comment: <input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>
 <img id='output' width=20> repeat this twice

Comment: @Teemu what if there are 10 images?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you're setting `input = event.target;`, `input` always refers to the clicked input element, hence you can find the image as the previous element or the next element related to the clicked input element, depending if the input element is placed before or after the image element in the markup.

Comment: See it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yx06wce/).

Comment: @Teemu, I understood that part of input.previousElementSibling. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The code below shows:**

- How to load multiple data urls with one file input and create an image box (image + file input + delete button) for each.
- How to individually change the loaded image for each image box.
- How to remove completely an image box.

**Snippet instructions:**

- Click the large blue '+' block to add **one or more** images to the list.
- Click an image to change it **individually**.
- Click the red cross in the top right corner of an image to remove it.

It's all file inputs under the hood (change the `hidden` class to reveal them), they're just hidden because it looks better.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('img_container');
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');

// utility function doing both createElement and setAttributes
function create(elementName, attributes) {
  var elem = document.createElement(elementName);
  if (typeof attributes === 'object') {
    Object.keys(attributes).forEach(function(attributeName) {
      elem.setAttribute(attributeName, attributes[attributeName]);
    });
  }
  return elem;
}

// load a file image as a data url and callback with this data url
function loadImage(file, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    var dataURL = this.result;
    callback(dataURL);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

// self explainatory
function createAndInsertNewImageBlock(id, dataURL) {
  var output = create('div', { 'class': 'img_block' });

  // image label, linked to the file input through their for/id attributes
  var label = create('label', { 'for': id, 'class': 'img_label' });
  var img = create('img', { 'class': 'image', src: dataURL });
  label.appendChild(img);
  output.appendChild(label);

  // single file input triggered by the image label, it is hidden
  var input = create(
    'input',
    {
      'type': 'file',
      'class': 'hidden',
      'accept': 'image/*',
      id: id
    }
  );
  // load single data url on change and change the image src
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    loadImage(this.files.item(0), function(data) {
      img.src = data;
    });
  });
  output.appendChild(input);

  // delete block button
  var cross = create('div', { 'class': 'cross' });
  cross.addEventListener('click', function() {
    output.remove();
  });
  output.appendChild(cross);

  // insert new image block just before the '+' placeholder
  container.insertBefore(output, placeholder);
}

// handler for the onChange event of the placeholder's file input
function openFiles(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files.item(i);
    loadImage(file, function(dataURL){
      var count = container.children.length;
      // lame unique id generation for linking label to input
      var id = 'img(' + count + '/' + (Date.now()).toString(16) + ')' + file.name;
      createAndInsertNewImageBlock(id, dataURL);
    });
  };
  
};
```

```css
#img_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: -9999px;
}
.img_block {
position: relative;
}
.img_label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plus {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #2060FF;
}
.plus:after {
content: '+';
}

.cross {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FF2060;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cross:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.cross:after {
content: 'x';
}
```

```html
<div id="img_container">
  <div id="placeholder">
    <label class="img_label" for="placeholder_input">
      <div class="plus"></div>
    </label>
    <input type='file' id="placeholder_input" class="hidden" accept="image/*" onchange='openFiles(event)' multiple>
  </div>
</div>
```